# How are stack pointers converted from virtual to physical memory

Tags: assembly, paging, virtual-memory

I've been working with a lot of assembly, and reviewing virtual memory I've run into some new confusion.

Briefly, I don't understand how an address in assembly, the code that interfaces with the processor directly, could be converted from a virtual address to a physical address.

I was always told that the operating system handled mapping from virtual to physical memory, but assembly directly references an address without any system calls, how could the OS intervene if it isn't called directly?

Where does an address, (mov eax, [0xDEADBEEF]), get translated from the virtual address space to the physical address space using the page table in the OS without specifically calling the OS?

Comment: The OS sets up the mapping in the CPU beforehand. The CPU does the translation by itself, and raises an exception if there is some problem. That's how the OS can get control to e.g. load pages back from paging file.

Comment: `x86` and `x86-64` use paging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table

Comment: Also osdev article on [MMU](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Management_Unit) and [paging](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) and obviously the official intel manuals.

Comment: the same way mail or a phone call gets forwarded.  it leaves you with the address you know but along the way the address gets changed by someone who knows both address spaces.  stack vs instruction fetches vs other non-stack data accesses have nothing to do with it.  the mmu translates addresses, and one of the major selling points is the software doesnt know the physical nor does it care it is very happy with its virtual space.

Comment: where is in the mmu which is usually between the processor core and the memory bus.

Comment: Applications normally operate in the virtual address space. Some device drivers do need to lock and then map virtual pages into physical addresses and lengths to work with bus master device types. For Windows device drivers, this is done by using the Windows functions associated with a [memory descriptor list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-mdls) .

Comment: Stack addresses aren't special, they're just part of the virtual address space of a process.  Anything you read about virtual memory applies to stack addresses used implicitly by `push`/`pop`, or explicitly like `mov eax, [rsp-8]`.

Comment: Thanks, the MMU and TLB being in the CPU, and faults going to the OS were what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because the CPU supports that kind of translation directly, using [page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table). OS sets up those page tables beforehand to tell CPU where to look when it references a memory address. That's how the translation happens transparently.

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten the TLB and the MMU were part of the cpu, not the OS

Answer (score 0):

In assembly language you work with logical addresses. The operating system maps logical addresses to physical addresses using page tables. The CPU automatically translates the local address to a physical address.

It is possible that a logical address will not have a physical address mapped to it. When the CPU encounters that condition it invokes the operating system's page fault handler.

The operating system has to maintain a copy the process's address space on secondary storage. This is the "virtual" memory. When a page fault occurs, the operating system determines if the page being referenced exists in virtual memory. If it does, the page fault handler reads the page into physical memory, alters the page tables to so the logical address maps to the correct physical address, then restarts the instruction.

If the virtual page does not exist, the operating system raises an access violation exception.

Comment: I understood that assembly was logical addresses, I was just confused on how logical addresses got translated into physical addresses at the cpu level because I had forgotten that the TLB and MMU were part of the CPU, and that faulting those tables resulted in a OS lookup.